# How to get Ancient Father of each son Recursive SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I've got this Original table:

[image]

And i need to Get this Table, By Recursive SQL Query (probably with 'With' clause) but not sure how to get it:

[image]

Would be glad if you can help,
thanks in advance

Comment: Why would the new node of `E` be `A`?  `A` is a _parent_ of `E`, not the other way around.  Please explain your logic.

Comment: I want to get the Ancient Father of each Original Node.A is the Ancient Father of E, like A is the Ancient Father of C and D.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Node, t1.Son, t1.Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), t1.Node + ',') AS path
    FROM yourTable t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t1.Node = t2.Son)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Node, t1.Son, t1.Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), path + ',' + t2.Son)
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.Node = t2.Son
)

SELECT
    ID,
    Node AS [Original Node],
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', path) = 0
         THEN path
         ELSE LEFT(path, CHARINDEX(',', path) - 1) END AS [New Node],
    Name
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Explanation: To understand how this works, it might be helpful to see the output of the following direct query on the CTE:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image]

Hopefully it is clear how the trick is working.  We recursively build a path, starting from all original ancestors.  When the recursive CTE completes, we have a table for which each node has a complete path going all the way back to the original ancestor.  Then, we only need to take the first term in the series to find that ancestor.

Comment: Thanks Tim, actually its a full Answer which Helps a lot. Only thing is the Name Field is not exactly the same.Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to answer myself, but not exactly with the Labels mentioned above.

```
Drop table if exists ##Nodes
CREATE TABLE ##Nodes
(
 NodeID varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
 SonNodeID varchar(20) NULL,
 [Name] varchar(20) NULL
)

    enter code here

INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('A', 'C','First')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('B', NULL,'Second')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('C', 'D','Third')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('D', 'E','Fourth')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('E', NULL,'Fifth')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('F', 'I','Sixth')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('G', NULL,'Seventh')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('H', NULL,'Eighth')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name]) VALUES ('I', NULL,'Nineth')

WITH Nodes AS
(
   --initialization
   SELECT NodeID, SonNodeID, [Name], Father = NodeID , 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM ##Nodes

   UNION ALL

   ----recursive execution
   SELECT N.NodeID, N.SonNodeID, P.[Name], Father = P.Father, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
   FROM Nodes AS P
      INNER JOIN ##Nodes AS N
      ON P.SonNodeID = N.NodeID
   WHERE P.GenerationsRemoved <= 100

)
SELECT a.NodeID, AncientFather = Father, a.[Name]
FROM    Nodes as a
        join 
            (
            Select  NodeID, MaxGen = max(GenerationsRemoved)
            from    Nodes 
            group by NodeID
            )as b   on a.NodeID = b.NodeID
                    and a.GenerationsRemoved = b.MaxGen
ORDER BY a.NodeID
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not perfect, but this one works fine and provides your desired result:

```
select t1.ID, t1.NODE as ORIGINAL_NODE,
CASE
   when t4.SON is not null then t4.NODE
   when t3.SON is not null then t3.NODE
   when t2.SON is not null then t2.NODE
   else t1.NODE
END as NEW_NODE,
CASE
   when t4.NAME is not null then t4.NAME
   when t3.NAME is not null then t3.NAME
   when t2.NAME is not null then t2.NAME
   else t1.NAME
END as NAME
from Table t1
left outer join Table t2
on t1.NODE = t2.SON
left outer join Table t3
on t2.NODE = t3.SON
left outer join Table t4
on t3.NODE = t4.SON
order by t1.ID
```